# can't output json object to html in angular and get pipe error

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

when i write

```
{{form}}
```

it's output
[object Object]
but when i write

```
{{form | json}}
```

```
ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TView'
    |     property 'blueprint' -> object with constructor 'LViewBlueprint'
    --- index 1 closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at JsonPipe.transform (common.mjs:4605)
    at Module.ɵɵpipeBind1 (core.mjs:22291)
    at UserSettingsFormsComponent_Template (user-settings-forms.component.html:97)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9603)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9469)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10640)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9265)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9519)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10640)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ScUd.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer here [Angular Json Pipe TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61577473/angular-json-pipe-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json?rq=1)
it must be writen

```
{{form.value|json}}
```